# String Formatting C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down control and the items look like this

```
Books(10)
Glasses(230)
Notebooks(27)
```

so basically i am grabbing the SelectedItem.Text; but I want to grab only the value before the amount in stock so when I grab it from SelectedItem.Text; it should look like this

```
string myString = (some code to get just the name without the stock i.e Books);
```

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you should be filling the values of the drop down control, and grabbing that. If possible.

Comment: Can anyone please take the negative vote, if not whats the reason of the negative vote so that i dont do it again. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the Split() method would work, this is more orthodox:

```
string myString = originalString.Substring(0, originalString.IndexOf("("));
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as the format is standard and the string you're interested in doesn't contain any parenthesis, you can use a simple `String.Split()` call to do the dirty work:

```
string myString = originalString.Split('(')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string myString = SelectedItem.Text.Substring(0, SelectedItem.Text.IndexOf('('));
```

Answer (score 0):

can you give me more information.  You`re books, Glasses, Notebooks are they build like this?

```
value="10" text="Books"
value="230" text="Glasses"
value="27" text="Notebooks"
```

if yes then you should build it like this:

```
string myString = dropdownlist.SelectedValue.toString();
```

If you want to fetch out the information and the complete text is Books(10)
 per exemple then I would do a split,

`string myString = dropdownlist.SelectedText.Text.Split('(')[0];`  <-- Which will give you the Books per exemple

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but perhaps something along these lines:

```
string colItem = comboControl.SelectedItem;

string formatedString = colItem.Substring(0 , ( colItem.IndexOF("(") -1 ) ) ;
```